# Selecting a drill through report in SSRS in a different folder if the report is not in current folder

Tags: reporting-services

I created a sub-folder for a older version of reports.  The current report version and older report version have drill through reports.  Some of the drill through reports will change and some will not.

I want to be able to select the drill through report that is in the current folder.  If there is no drill through report in the current folder, that go to the current version which will be one folder 1 level up.

This is the folder structure.
MainRptFolder - this folder has all of the current reports and drill through reports.
MainRptFolder/OldReports - this folder has the older reports and drill through reports.

Currently, I use the Built-in field, `Globals!ReportFolder`.  This returns the path of the current main report.  So, if the old report is in `MainRptFolder/OldReports`, the expression returns this path.  But if the drill through report is not in this folder, I would like the path be `MainRptFolder`. I would not like to hard-code the folder name.

How can I reset the folder path to the main folder if the drill through report is not in the subfolder, `OldReports`?

Comment: Is it maybe possible to add a dataset that looks for the drill-through report in the current folder in the Catalog table of the ReportServer database, and sets a flag for whether the report exists there or not? Then for your drill through action, you could have an expression for which report to go to based on the results of that flag?

Comment: I will look into that...thanks.

Comment: To change the report folder path, would you have to just use text functions to set the folder path?

Comment: What I would do is based on the flag from the query that checks if the report exists in the current folder, my Action would have an expression to decide what path to use. That expression might look something like this:  
`=IIf(Sum(Fields!ReportExists.Value, "Exists") = 1, "MainRptFolder/Report", "MainRptFolder/OldReports/Report")`  
I have it as a sum because without testing it myself and without knowing how your report is structured, I don't know for sure that just calling Fields!ReportExists.Value will give you what you want, but summing the dataset should.

Comment: You could also have your query for that additional dataset return the actual path that you need instead of just a flag, that may or may not work better.